# Adobe Illustrator 2019 stroke issue

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

Since updating to the 2019 version of Illustrator, I am having this issue with the stroke that crops up randomly for certain elements.

**On applying stroke, the stroke on the left doesn't show up on random elements**. I used the eyedropper tool to make sure that no properties were different and even then, the problem persists.

Here's a screenshot demonstrating the issue
[image: Left stroke issue]

As you can see from the stroke on the innermost box, the stroke goes around it. But even using eyedropper tool from that box renders the missing left stroke on this particular box.

Here's the funny part. When I take the buggy box as the reference for the eyedropper tool and copy the style to some other rectangle, that renders properly.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Pixel preview? Align to Pixel Grid?

Comment: @Scott - Pixel preview is turned off (I turned it on and there was no change) and I have everything set to snap in the Align to Pixel Grid option (changing those also did not have any affect)

Comment: What about switching the CPU/GPU review? (View menu)

Comment: Have you tried to change zoom level?

Comment: Did all of that. No change. I'd like to reiterate; this is only happening to certain elements